# Next.js (13.3.1) Build failing

Tags: next.js

I'm using the experimental app directory and everything runs smoothly on local. However, I keep encountering build failures and the error message provided isn't particularly helpful.

Error Message:

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build .info  - TypeError: Expected a non-empty string
    at picomatch.makeRe (/Users/himanshubhardwaz/web/personal/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:21418)
    at micromatch.makeRe (/Users/himanshubhardwaz/web/personal/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:2615)
    at /Users/himanshubhardwaz/web/personal/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1758:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/himanshubhardwaz/web/personal/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1753:155
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/himanshubhardwaz/web/personal/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:97:20)
    at async build (/Users/himanshubhardwaz/web/personal/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:143:29)
```

I tried clearing the build cache, re-installing node modules, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

Do u have this code in ur next.config ?

```
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'localhost:3000',
        port: '',
        pathname: '',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Try to delete this or edit pathname

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was misconfiguration in `next.config.js`

I had an empty pathname in my remotePatterns config